# Set value to the radio button in the radio group in Android

Tags: android, radio-button, set, realm, radio-group

I am building an app where I have radio group with three radio buttons. What I want is when I check the radio button I need to get the value of that radio button and save it in the realm database.
And after that I want to get that radio button value from the Realm database and assign that value  to another radio button.

For example: if I select radio button of radio group1 then I need to set that value to the radio button in the group2.

Here is an example:

activity_main.xml

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1">

            <RadioButton
                android:text="On Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fontimeRadio" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Delay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fdelayRadio" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Not"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fnotRadio" />


        </RadioGroup>

          <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/RadioGroup2">

            <RadioButton
                android:text="On Time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fontimeRadio1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Delay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fdelayRadio1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:text="Not"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:id="@+id/fnotRadio1" />


        </RadioGroup>
```

Model.java

```
   public class Model extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
private int id;
private boolean radiocheck;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public boolean getRadioCheck() {
    return radiocheck;
}
public void setRadioCheck(boolean radiocheck) {
    this.radiocheck= radiocheck;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
        RadioGroup radiocheck1= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
        RadioGroup radiocheck2= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup2);
```

Now please tell me how to get the value from the selected radio button and save it in the Realm database and retrieve that value to set into the another radio button.

For example we use

```
textview.setText(model.getName());
```

to set the text from the database but how to do that for radio buttons based on the above `Model.java` class as I have used the boolean function for radio button declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You can select radio group and set text to radio button using loop.

```
RadioGroup rbtnGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

((RadioButton) rbtnGrp.getChildAt(2)).setText("your radio button data");
```

Comment: I want to add a value to the radio button like for text view we use **setText** function. So for in place of text view i have radio button so how to do with that.

Comment: check my updated answer it will set text to radio buttons

Comment: see i have two radio buttons. now i am getting value from one radio button and save the selected values as a string. Now i wanna set that saved string value to the another radio button. can you help me in this

Comment: you have a radio group from one you can get data and update if over second one.

Comment: the answer which you posted is setting the text of the radio button.for example if the radio button1 text is "on time" its been showing in radio button2.  But what i want is if i have checked the radio button from group1 say "on time" the that value should be checked in the radio button of group 2.

Comment: Example:         if radio button from group1 is checked (say "on time") then i want that value to be checked in radio button of group2(say "on time"). please someone help me

Comment: you have groups of two buttons are you able to get data from one ?

Comment: yes i can. but i want to set that data value to the next group button

Comment: My answer is for that only please check the answer

Comment: What is that 2 value respresents?

Comment: second radio button is represented by 2

Comment: Data taken from radio button one will be set using id 2.